# IP-TV через прокси на Squid на Ubuntu

Tags: squid, ubuntu

Есть прокси-сервер на Ubuntu 12.04.LTS. Поднят Squid 2.7. Squid сконфигурирован минимально. Через него руководство ходит в Интернет. Выразило желание получать от провайдера Ip-TV. На данной конфигурации IP-TV не получается. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что нужно сделать, может: - установить и сконфигурировать NAT и Iptables; - как то разрешить в Squid протокол IGMP;  - правильно сконфигурировать IP-TV Player. Что делать?

Comment: А нужно именно IPTV? Нынче в моде P2P-TV! Это тоже потоковое вещание, но по пиринговой схеме и протоколу (типа как торренты). Вот тут, например, есть: http://banan.tv/tv/ Торренты-то хоть там работают? Если же всё очень сурово, и только через Squid, то можно попробовать SOCKS5. Есть, кстати, очень хорошая прога - вот тут: http://www.proxycap.com/ , которая позволяет работать через SOCKS даже тем прогам, которые этого изначально не умеют! Но увы! Она только под венды или макось.

Comment: http://www.tonchik.ru/pub/over/Linux%20Multicast%20Routing%20with%20IGMPProxy.html

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Торренты ходят. Пробовал проигрыватель Р2Р - большие тормоза. Но работает. Руководство хочет смотреть телепрограммы (типа кабельное) по компьютеру. Буду рыть дальше.

Answer (score 1):

Вот [это](http://www.udpxy.com/) Вам поможет.[Вот](http://91.205.164.201/yalta-tv-http.m3u) пример плей-листа